# If a quadrilateral is a parallelogram and a rhombus, does that imply it is a square?

Tags: geometry

I have proven that a quadrilateral is a parallelogram, and that it is also a rhombus. Does this imply that it is ultimately a square?

I believe it does because all sides are equal, and opposite sides are parallel, and I believe the only way this is possible is if the angles are all 90, but I'm not sure if that is true. +1 if you can link to a proof that says that (or prove it yourself).

Comment: You probably mean "rectangle and rhombus = square".

Comment: @lhf No, I meant parallelagram and rhombus. I was just wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every rhombus is a parallelogram and a rhombus with right angles is a square.  Hence a quadrilateral which is a rhombus is a parallelogram, but not necessarily a square.

Comment: Whoops, forgot rhombus has to be parallel. You are correct, thanks.

Comment: No problems @ Dgrin91

Comment: As a side note, Euclid's original definition of rhombus actually excludes a square ... so you have to be careful.

Answer (score 2):

A rhombus is always a parallelogram.  In order to guarantee that you have a square, you'd have to show that all four angles are congruent.